# Time-Complexity of the problem in CodeForces contest #771

Tags: python, time-complexity

I'm currently trying to upsolve one problem from CodeForces and I face so many time issues. I've tried a variety of modifications, however my code still doesn't get submitted.

**Any suggestions on how I can improve the time complexity of my code?**

The main idea of the problem can be found here: https://codeforces.com/contest/1638/problem/C

A description of the problem is as follows:

> You are given a permutation p_1,p_2,…,p_n. Then, an undirected graph is constructed in the following way: add an edge between vertices i, j such that i < j if and only if p_i > p_j. Your task is to count the number of connected components in this graph.
>
> Two vertices u and v belong to the same connected component if and only if there is at least one path along edges connecting u and v.
>
> A permutation is an array consisting of n distinct integers from 1 to n in arbitrary order. For example, [2,3,1,5,4] is a permutation, but [1,2,2] is not a permutation (2 appears twice in the array) and [1,3,4] is also not a permutation (n=3 but there is 4 in the array).
>
> **Input**
>
> Each test contains multiple test cases. The first line contains a single integer t (1 ≤ t ≤ 10**5) — the number of test cases. Description of the test cases follows.
>
> The first line of each test case contains a single integer n (1 ≤ n ≤ 10**5) — the length of the permutation.
>
> The second line of each test case contains n integers p_1,p_2,…,p_n (1≤p_i≤n) — the elements of the permutation.
>
> It is guaranteed that the sum of n over all test cases does not exceed 2⋅10**5.
>
> **Output**
>
> For each test case, print one integer k — the number of connected components.

```
import sys
input = sys.stdin.readline
     
for case in range(int(input())):
    length = int(input())
    line = list(map(int, input().split()))
    
    quantity = 0
    for i in range(1, length):
        if line[i] > line[i-1] and max(line[:i]) < min(line[i:]):
            quantity += 1
                
    print(1 if quantity >= length else quantity + 1)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Time should only be a factor in large lists, and in that case your `max` and `min` calls are going to make this O(N**2).  I wonder if you shouldn't make a pass through the list to cache the min-to-this-point and max-after-this-point values.

Comment: @TimRoberts any way I can modificate this code so it still goes with the same logic?

Comment: I go by the logic of making cuts in a particular position to separate not connected vertices and then output the number of cuts + 1.

Answer (score -1):

This implements my min/max caching scheme.  I have not submitted this, so I don't actually know if it will meet the timing.  This is O(3N) instead of O(N*N), so it will take slightly longer for short lists, but SHOULD be better for long lists.

You don't need to do `input = sys.stdin.readline`; that's effectively what the `input` function already is.  Also, the `if` clause in your final line confuses me.  Your final `for` can never go more than length-1 iterations, so `quantity` can never be >= length.

```
import sys
     
for case in range(int(input())):
    length = int(input())
    line = list(map(int, input().split()))
    maxx = 0
    maxs = []
    for i in line:
        if i > maxx:
            maxx = i
        maxs.append(maxx)
    minx = 999999
    mins = []
    for i in line[::-1]:
        if i < minx:
            minx = i
        mins.insert(0,minx)
    
    quantity = 0
    for i in range(1, length):
        if line[i] > line[i-1] and maxs[i-1] < mins[i]:
            quantity += 1
                
    print(quantity + 1)
```

You can replace the final section of the code with a comprehension, although I think that's a micro-optimization:

```
    quantity = sum(
        line[i] > line[i-1] and maxs[i-1] < mins[i]
        for i in range(1, length)
    )
                
    print(quantity + 1)
```

Comment: This code has failed. However doesn't stdin.readline() make input faster? And in my implementation the quantity goes higher than length when there are no separated components.

Comment: It might be advantageous to use a `collections.deque` for `mins`, that way you can `appendleft` rather than `insert`

Comment: *"that's exactly what the `input` function already is"* - That's not true.

Comment: Did it fail a test, or did it time out?

Comment: Actually I modified that code so now it passes all tests fast enough, thank you Tim and @C.Nivs.

Comment: @KellyBundy, you need to grasp the difference between "differences that matter" and "differences that are irrelevant".  `input` calls `PyFile_GetLine` which calls `f.readline` and then strips the newline.

Comment: @TimRoberts could you run me through the maxs and mins concept again please, I see what they are for, but would be better if that will be sorted in my head a bit more

Comment: Without sys.stdin.readline the runtime doesn't fit the conditions, just checked it

Comment: @TimRoberts "is exactly" is *far* from "irrelevant differences". And since `readline` can be more than ten times faster and the OP has a time limit problem, I even disagree that the differences are irrelevant.

Comment: Checked it myself as well now, after making the `mins` calculation linear (it's *not* O(3N) as you claim), this still consistently exceeds the time limit of 1000 ms, but with `readline`, it consistently gets accepted with about 230 ms (PyPy) or 430 ms (CPython).

Comment: @C.Nivs Indeed. I tried computing `mins` with n=10^5 (the limit) and using deque dropped the time from 2050 ms to 12.5 ms. With `itertools.accumulate` I got 25 ms, and the fastest I managed was 6.7 ms. [Results/code](https://pastebin.com/raw/xqnTJdJM)

Comment: *run me through the concept* -- In your code, you are computing `max(line[i:])` and `min(line[:i])` for every number.  Each one has to scan through the whole list.  Since those values are constant for a given set of input, we can compute them beforehand.  So `maxs[i]` == `max(line[i:])`, but doesn't have to scan the whole list.

Comment: I see, thank you @TimRoberts